# IntelliJ keeps resetting source location

Tags: intellij-idea

2 Projects. Project Dependency, Project Application.

Project Application gets Project Dependency's jars from .m2. It is set up so that all sources from all the different modules are linked to their respective jars in .m2. Perfect.

Then I run `gradle publishtomavenlocal` in Project Dependency.

All settings on where the sources are in Project Application gets lost.

How to make IntelliJ stop acting smart and make the setting stick?

Comment: Publish the sources in your local Maven repo, too, and let IntelliJ download them and make the link for you.

Comment: If you are using Maven/Gradle then all the project structure configurations (dependencies, sources/resources locations etc) must be made in corresponding pom.xml/build.gradle files. Otherwise all your manual changes of the IDE settings will be lost on re-import from Maven/Gradle.